# Error on creating a .wxs file for Wix Toolset 4.0.1

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm completely new on this and I'm trying to create a .wxs file to create a .msi installer for a .dll that I created.

I've checked Wix documentation and asked help for chatgpt as well, but no success to fix the problem.

Below my .wxs xml:

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs">
    <Product Id="*" Name="RTD Installer" Version="0.0.1" Manufacturer="ksr" Language="1033" UpgradeCode="{00F8DEE0-EEEE-FFFF-AAAA-623A8A8007D3">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine"/>
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Uma versão mais recente já está instalada."/>
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents"/>
        </Feature>

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="RTD">
                    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents">
                        <Component Id="ProductComponent">
                            <File Source="bin/Release/RTDService.dll"/>
                            <Class Id="{4b000004-0000-0000-0000-90000615130d}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="RTD Server" ThreadingModel="apartment">
                                <ProgId Id="RTD" Description="RTD Server" />
                            </Class>
                        </Component>
                    </ComponentGroup>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <!-- Propriedades e atualizações movidas para dentro do Product -->
        <Property Id="ARPCOMMENTS" Value="RTD Server"/>
        <Property Id="ARPHELPLINK" Value="http://rtd.ksr.com.br/help"/>
        <Property Id="ARPURLINFOABOUT" Value="http://rtd.ksr.com.br"/>
        <Property Id="ARPURLUPDATEINFO" Value="http://rtd.ksr.com.br/update"/>
        <Property Id="ARPREADME" Value="Leia-me"/>
        <Property Id="ARPCONTACT" Value="suporte@ksr.com.br"/>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

I'm getting the following error when executing the `wix build ExQuoteService.wxs`:

`error WIX0005: The Wix element contains an unexpected child element 'Product'.`

- How to fix the .wxs xml file for the Wix 4.0.1+6e6eb478 ?
- What are the commands to get the .msi installer file ?

Answer (score 2):

As per [the WiX v4 documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/wxs/), there is no `Product` element in WiX v4 any longer. What you have there is v3 .wxs code with the v4 namespace. Maybe you are still reading the v3 documentation?

It might be easier to put the namespace back to the v3 namespace and use the [conversion tooling to upgrade](https://www.firegiant.com/docs/heatwave/convert-or-create/) for you.

You might also find [the Deployment Dojo show](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDlzbQXIs18slmqmdlS10_de_Cps-QRg6) useful. I cover these topics there.

Comment: Hi Rob. Yes, I saw the documentation that there is no Product tag. But as my knowledge in Wix is 0, I couldn't fix the xml. BTW, the .wxs in the post was created by chatGPT and it couldn't fix it for wix 4.x as well. Can you help with a fixed one ?

Comment: ChatGPT will happily lie to you. To use it responsibly, you need to have a working understanding of the topic you're having a conversation about or you can be led into some very dark places. I'd recommend getting some WiX fundamentals under your belt before depending on ChatGPT. There are tutorials on firegiant.com if you prefer to read and my Deployment Dojo show is available if you prefer to watch.

Comment: I reccomend reading through this and giving it a try. https://github.com/iswix-llc/iswix-tutorials